# returning values from async functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

I have the following snippet

```
"use strict"

const req = require('requisition');

async function doRequest () {
  const url = 'http://api.com/v3/search?q=breno'
  const res = await req.get(url)

  console.log(res.status)

  const body = await res.json();

  return "it Works!"
}


console.log(doRequest())
```

the requests are working just fine, but the console.log() produces:

```
{}
200
```

instead of

```
200
"it Works!"
```

when I try to:

```
console.log(await doRequest())
```

i get an `Unexpected Token` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` functions return **promises**. At the top level you have to "subscribe" to the promise:

```
doRequest().then(result => console.log(result));
```